# INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Package /data/app/vmdl2005941423.tmp/0_base-master has no certificates at entry AndroidManifest.xml.

Tags: android, android-signing

Environment: Windows 10 64 bit, Android Studio 3.2 Canary 15.

I have added **free** and **paid** flavours to a test project and than built signed APK's.

When Running the release APK's I get the following error -

```
Installation failed with message Failed to finalize session : 
INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Package 
/data/app/vmdl2005941423.tmp/0_base-master has no certificates at entry 
AndroidManifest.xml.
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing 
version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.
```

I tried to re sign my APK with both V1 and V2 signature versions and still I get the same error when running release versions.

After analyzing the release APK's it turns out that AndroidManifest.xml shows the xmlns:android of the Manifest tag in red :

```
    <manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

When I hover the red text it says "URI is not registered..."

I have no idea what it means...

What is the cause for this error ?

Answer (score 1):

According [here](https://github.com/google/bundletool/issues/8),

> When building the APK Set, set the --ks and --ks-key-alias flags to ensure that the APKs are signed. Only signed APKs can be installed on a device.
>   The Android SDK should come with a debug keystore. Try looking under ~/.android/debug.keystore (alias: AndroidDebugKey, pwd: android).

In other words, only signed apk could be install to devices. This makes sense since App Bundle is really use for distribution.

Comment: So this means we can not even run debug version of application for testing and development purpose. Actually I am encountering the same problem when I run using debug keystore

Comment: You don't have to sign your apk just to run a debug version of your app. Debug Keystore isn't a valid signing key. You could sign your apk with it but you cannot distribute that APK.